# An established connection on glassfish is aborted when I use jnlp file

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

Im having a strange problem. I have a java software that uses web services that run on glassfish4. When I run the program from my Netbeans everything works fine. When I run the program using a generated jnlp file then certain web services cause the program to freeze. The log on my server shows the following:

```
StandardWrapperValve[default]: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Connection closed
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:969)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:686)
.....other stuff
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
```

This does not happen when I run the program directly from Netbeans even though I use the exact same web services. Any idea?

Comment: Does the machine have a software firewall?

Comment: check the firewall settings. Most probably it is blocking the connection. If so you can add exception to the firewall

Comment: There is a firewall but there are rules to allow connection via the proper ports. If it was a firewall problem then I wouldn't be able to connect from the program in Netbeans where I call the same web services.

Comment: I turned off the firewall on the server but still have the same problem.

Comment: try testing the web-service with SOAP UI. Why are you using Web-start for  a web-service client?

Comment: I have updated my question after identifying why the error is arising. I use java web start so that the program will be updated when there are updates.